# Differences between 2 instances of the same classe

Tags: php, class, oop

I came with this idea because of the following problem:

Imagine that I have the following class:

```
Class Plane {

    public $color;
    public $metal;
    public $motor;

}
```

Pretty simple, but imagine that is stored in db and have a model with this and bla bla bla, and user can update it. So when the user creates a new plane it will be:

```
new Plane("Yellow","Iron","2000cv");
```

And this is storage on database, and in this that database i have a log table to track who and when this was change, but today i dont have **what** was change so my question is, **How i can take two instances of same class and in a function for example output the diferences of this classes?**

The old plane is that:

```
new Plane("Yellow","Iron","2000cv");
```

And the new one is that:

```
new Plane("Blue","Chrome","2000cv");
```

And some function that recieves both instances and output that:

```
Array(
    'color'=>Array(
      'old'=>'Yellow',
      'new'=>'Blue'
     ),
    'metal'=>Array(
      'old'=>'Iron',
      'new'=>'Chrome'
    )
)
```

I know how to do it with ifs and wherever but i don't know if is the best approach.

Comment: In the model you usually only keep the actual data, not the delta or the past data. You can have a history table like you said, but I don't understand why you want the difference in the PHP model?

Comment: Yeah is that in the database that i ll store not in the model, maybe i write whrong, what i need is just a function with good practices for that Actually

Comment: What DanFromGermany said is the best approach. If you want to keep a history of anything, permanent storage is the way to go. Keep it in a database.

Comment: Before you update the database record, just copy it to a history table. Then you have a log of who changed what when.

Comment: i know guys what i wold like to know if is there a way to have a function that return just the differences, if there some php command that already do that, or i need to parse the objects in arrays and the use some array_diff or array_diff_assoc

Comment: If you can get the data into arrays, you can use array_diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you store two objects in the database and want to compare them. Right?

Suppose you have these two objects;

```
$plane_one = new Plane ( 'Yellow', 'Iron', '2000cv' );
$plane_two = new Plane ( 'Blue', 'Chrome', '2000cv' );
```

## Method 1

This one is actually not adviseable, as the code isn't maintainable, but hey, it works.

```
function comparePlanes ( &obj1, &$obj2 ) {
    $differences = array ();

    if ( $obj1->color != $obj2->color ) {
        $differences['color'] => array($obj1->color, $obj2->color);
    }

    if ( $obj1->metal != $obj2->metal ) {
        $differences['metal'] => array($obj1->metal, $obj2->metal);
    }

    if ( $obj1->motor != $obj2->motor ) {
        $differences['motor'] => array($obj1->motor, $obj2->motor);
    }

    return $differences;
}
```

This would return;

```
Array (
    'color' => Array('Yellow', 'Blue'),
    'metal' => Array('Iron', 'Chrome')
)
```

## Method 2

More fun would it be when your function would just spit out all differences between all properties, while being agnostic to which properties there are. For this we can use the [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

```
function compareObjects( &$obj1, &$obj2 ) {
    if ( ! is_object($obj1) || ! is_object($obj2) || get_class($obj1) != get_class($obj2) ) {
        return array(); // One of them isn't an object, or they are not from the same class
    }

    $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($obj1));
    $properties = $reflection->getProperties();

    $differences = array();
    foreach( $properties as $property ) {
        if ( $obj1->{$property->name} != $obj2->{$property->name} ) {
            $differences[$property->name] = array($obj1->{$property->name}, $obj2->{$property->name});
        }
    }
    return $differences;
}
```

Now this would output the exact same. But if you would now alter your class to hold the number of passengers for example;

```
class Plane {
    ...

    public $passengers;

    ...

    function __construct($color, $metal, $motor, $passengers) {
        ...
        $this->passengers = $passengers;
    }
}
```

And you would input these two objects;

```
$plane_one = new Plane ( 'Yellow', 'Iron', '2000cv', 12 );
$plane_two = new Plane ( 'Blue', 'Chrome', '2000cv', 6 );
```

You would get the differences as well;

```
Array (
    [color] => Array ( 'Yellow', 'Blue' ),
    [metal] => Array ( 'Iron', 'Chrome' ),
    [passengers] => Array ( 12, 6 )
)
```

You can even pass any other pair of objects if you want to. Doesn't matter

Comment: Man...that was mystic, exactly what i need, thank you very much

Comment: @AugustoCoelhoHenriques if is what you need, please accept the answer.